# Pandas: reading from multiple files with different variable ordering

Tags: python, pandas

I have many files that I'd like to read into a single pandas data frame. An example file might look like this:

```
variable_1_name
variable_2_name
...
variable_n_name
0.0  0.5  0.3  ...  0.8
...
1.0  4.5  6.5  ...  1.0
```

So, the file has a list of variable names (one per line) at the top of the file and then the data is presented in a space delimited table with `n` values per row.

There are a couple of problems:

1) There is a different number of variables in each file. Not all variables are present in each file.

2) The variables may be in different order between files.

How can I read all this data into a panadas data frame, while matching up the correct data between files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending [Pal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8802367/pal)'s answer: the best way is to read data out of csv files. So why not converting the files to csv files (or even better, csv file-like objects living in memory) and let `pandas` do the dirty work?

```
try:
    import io  # python3
except ImportError:
    import cStringIO as io  # python2
import pandas as pd

DELIMITER = ','

def pd_read_chunk(file):
    """
    Reads file contents, converts it to a csv file in memory
    and imports a dataframe from it.
    """
    with open(file) as f:
        content = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
        cols = [line for line in content if ' ' not in line]
        vals = [line for line in content if ' ' in line]
        csv_header = DELIMITER.join(cols)
        csv_body = '\n'.join(DELIMITER.join(line.split()) for line in vals)
        stream = io.StringIO(csv_header + '\n' + csv_body)
        return pd.read_csv(stream, sep=DELIMITER)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ('file1', 'file2', )
    # read dataframe from each file and concat all resulting dataframes
    df_chunks = [pd_read_chunk(file) for file in files]
    df = pd.concat(df_chunks)
    print(df)
```

If you try out the sample files from [Thom Ives](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996205/thom-ives)' answer, the script will return

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  1.1  2.1  3.1  NaN  NaN
0  NaN  2.2  NaN  4.2  5.2
1  NaN  2.3  NaN  4.3  5.3
```

---

**Edit**: Actually, we don't need the comma delimiter - we can reuse space as the delimiter so we can compact and speed up the conversion at the same time. Here is an updated version of the one above that has less code and runs faster:

```
try:
    import io  # python3
except ImportError:
    import cStringIO as io  # python2
import pandas as pd


def pd_read_chunk(file):
    """
    Reads file contents, converts it to a csv file in memory
    and imports a dataframe from it.
    """
    with open(file) as f:
        content = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
        cols = [line for line in content if ' ' not in line]
        vals = [line for line in content if ' ' in line]
        csv_header = ' '.join(cols)
        csv_lines = [csv_header] + vals
        stream = io.StringIO('\n'.join(csv_lines))
        return pd.read_csv(stream, sep=' ')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ('file1', 'file2', )
    # read dataframe from each file and concat all resulting dataframes
    df_chunks = [pd_read_chunk(file) for file in files]
    df = pd.concat(df_chunks)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to edit the text file in the following way and use read_csv

```
variable_1_name, variable_2_name, ..., variable_n_name
0.0  0.5  0.3  ...  0.8
...
1.0  4.5  6.5  ...  1.0

df = pd.read_csv('filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's NOT easy to do what Pal has said in his good suggestion, say you have two simplified data files:

data1.txt

```
A
B
C
1.0 2.0 3.0
1.1 2.1 3.1
```

and data2.txt

```
B
D
E
2.2 4.2 5.2
2.3 4.3 5.3
```

use something like the following two functions to 1) get the files that you want, and 2) condition them into pandas dataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def Get_Filtered_File_List(topDirectory, checkString = None):
    fileList = []

    fileNamesList = os.listdir(topDirectory)
    for fileName in fileNamesList:
        if checkString == None or checkString in fileName:
            fileList.append(fileName)

    return fileList

def Load_And_Condition_Files_Into_DF(fileList):
    header = []
    arrayOfValues = []
    arrayOfDicts = []

    for file in fileList:
        thisHeader = []
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            arrayOfLines = f.readlines()
            for line in arrayOfLines:

                lineArray = line.split()
                if len(lineArray) == 1:
                    thisHeader.append(lineArray[0])
                else:
                    arrayOfDicts.append({})
                    for i in range(len(lineArray)):
                        arrayOfDicts[-1][thisHeader[i]] = lineArray[i]

            header += thisHeader

    # print arrayOfDicts
    header = sorted(list(set(header)))
    for dict in arrayOfDicts:
        arrayOfValues.append([])
        for name in header:
            try:
                val = dict[name]
                # print '\t', name, val
                arrayOfValues[-1].append(val)
            except:
                # print '\t', name, None
                arrayOfValues[-1].append(None)
    table = [header] + arrayOfValues
    # print table
    return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=table.pop(0))


fileList = Get_Filtered_File_List('./','data')
print Load_And_Condition_Files_Into_DF(fileList)
```

Which outputs:

```
      A    B     C     D     E
0   1.0  2.0   3.0  None  None
1   1.1  2.1   3.1  None  None
2  None  2.2  None   4.2   5.2
3  None  2.3  None   4.3   5.3
```